# Is there any ready-to-go malware analysis/reverse engineering OS? (That is capable of installing on hard disk, preferably)

Tags: operating-systems

I just wanted to know if there's any ready-to-go OS for malware analysis/reverse engineering? I prefer OS that is capable of installing on real hardware, not a VM.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. This question isn't really a good fit for Q&A (as it elicits opinion-based responses), but I'll defer to the community on this one. However, it's a bit unclear also what you're after. Do you mean an OS that could, say, run a sandbox in which the malware gets analyzed? Do you mean simply a desktop system (Kali comes to mind) which comes with a lot of RCE and forensics tools? Could you please clarify?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- FireEye's [FLARE VM](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2017/07/flare-vm-the-windows-malware.html)

  > FLARE VM is a freely available and open sourced Windows-based security
  >   distribution designed for reverse engineers, malware analysts,
  >   incident responders, forensicators, and penetration testers. Inspired
  >   by open-source Linux-based security distributions like Kali Linux,
  >   REMnux and others, FLARE VM delivers a fully configured platform with
  >   a comprehensive collection of Windows security tools such as
  >   debuggers, disassemblers, decompilers, static and dynamic analysis
  >   utilities, network analysis and manipulation, web assessment,
  >   exploitation, vulnerability assessment applications, and many others.
  >
  > The distribution also includes the FLARE team’s public malware
  >   analysis tools such as FLOSS and FakeNet-NG.
- Kali Linux

  - [Forensics tools included by default](https://tools.kali.org/tools-listing):
    Binwalk, bulk-extractor, Capstone, chntpw, Cuckoo dc3dd, ddrescue, DFF, diStorm3, Dumpzilla, extundelete, Foremost, Galleta, Guymager, iPhone Backup Analyzer, p0f, pdf-parser, pdfid, pdgmail, peepdf, RegRipper, Volatility,
    Xplico
  - ["Forensics mode"](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-forensics-mode)
- [Tsurugi Linux](https://tsurugi-linux.org/tsurugi_linux.php)

  - > Tsurugi is an heavily customized Linux distribution designed to
    >   support your DFIR investigations, malware analysis and open source
    >   intelligence activities.
    >
    > In this distribution are included the latest versions of the most
    >   famous tools you need to conduct an in-depth forensic or incident
    >   response investigation and several useful features like device write
    >   blocking at kernel level, an OSINT profile switcher and much more!

Comment: No way! I never imagined things like Flare VM or Tsurugi Linux can exist! Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: @JerryEasley you are welcome